# Autocomplete like google plugin not working (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to use this plugin for Jquery, but the remote option for fetch data from database, and I can't make work.

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/

The autocomplete function is calling fine the remote url teste_search.asp, but I dont know if on this page I need format the data like this:

`['produto abc', 'produto xyz', 'produto 123']`

OR like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Cuba Gold Masculino Eau de Toilette 100ml"
  },
  {
    "title": "Cuba Jungle Zebra Feminino Eau de Parfum 100ml"
  },
  {
    "title": "Cuba Blue Masculino Eau de Toilette 100ml"
  }
]
```

Here's my code:

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin:20px 0px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="remote_input" placeholder="Enter movie">
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
    $("#remote_input").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [
            function(q,add){
                $.getJSON("../../../teste_search.asp?q=" + q, function(resp) {
                    add(resp);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```

So I dont know if the problem is on this function or the data format...

Comment: Based on the Docs you provided, the example data is an Array only. So your first response seems to be what it wants.

Comment: Right, but even with this array, this remote option don’t work.. Maybe the Jquery function is incorrect?

Comment: The Function looks correct. I would check your Network console to see if the data coming back is correct. If `resp` is an array of String items, it should be correct,. If it is something else, you may need to adjust. Also do you see any Errors in Console?

Comment: When you navigate to `../../../teste_search.asp?q=test` what do you get?

Comment: The path is correct. Is calling the .asp file. I have 2 files, teste_search1 and teste_search2. The first one is returning correctly the array in the console, which I also tried with and without brackets and the second one the json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the function below together with the json data source:

```
$('#remote_input').autocomplete({
valueKey:'title',
accents:true,
replaceAccentsForRemote: true,
source:[{
    url:"https://www.example.com/teste2/teste_search2.asp?q=%QUERY% ",
    type:'remote',
    getValueFromItem:function(item){
        return item.title
    },
    ajax:{
        dataType : 'json'   
    }
}]});
```

Important: `Datatype` need to be `json` instead `jsonp`